# Deploy Machine Learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, deployment

I created a Machine Learning pipeline from training the model and deploy it as a web service. I put everything on Github but I did not put the training dataset as Github limits file size up to 100 MB. After I train the model, I save the model and necessary files into .pkl file. The model file size itself ~300 MB so I can't upload the model to Github. I connected my repo to Heroku and try to send a request but then I realized that I do not have the model along the training dataset  so I can't make a request.

Is there any best practice to do deploy Machine Learning model considering some limitation from Github?

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is a version control system. Technically, your repository should not contain training data or trained models.

The most real-life Machine Learning systems store trained models in the file storage, for instance [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).